# Did Apple drop/ reduce support for Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast

It appears to me that it is getting increasingly difficult to cast to Chromecast from my iPhone (iOS 16.1.2). Most apps still support it, but neither Safari nor Edge or Chrome allow me to cast a video to Chromecast, only to Airplay.

I don’t cast so much, so this may have been so for a while, but I’m wondering: is Apple making it more difficult for developers to have their app support Chromecast or how can we understand that not even Chrome can cast to Chromecast?

Comment: I've been a long time Apple user and stayed away from Google stuff as much as possible, but I don't remember Apple ever *natively* supporting Chromecast.  I remember having to use an App to broadcast to a Chomecast device (like a TV or projector)

Answer (score 4):

Apple has never supported Chromecast from its built-in apps like Safari.

There haven't been any substantial changes for developers to cast to Chromecast. One notable one – a number of years ago (not recent) – was the "Local network" prompt you might've seen. Chromecast requires communicating across the local network, and iOS requires user permission to do that.

However, I wouldn't say this is a significant blocker. If the developer properly configures their app to wait to prompt until the user first tries to invoke Chromecast, it will be clear why they need the permission.

Comment: Could you also say something about why not even the Chrome app can cast to Chromecast when streaming a video? I would assume that Google would want to make sure that this works, so since it doesn't, I'd assume it has to do with some iOS restrictions. Yet, there are plenty of apps (Netflix, Youtube, Emby, ...) that offer Chromecasting without ay problem.

Comment: There should be no reason that the Chrome app can no longer Chromecast, unless you've rejected the local networking prompt I mentioned.

Comment: Are you saying that your chrome app can chromecast? Mine can Airplay but not chromecast. Not because of permissions but because it doesn’t even offer the option.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I meant that if it used to work, there's no reason [caused by iOS] for it to stop working.

Comment: Just to add somethings that I have noticed regarding Chromecast SDK for iOS: 1. The SDK is not of very good quality and feels very "old". 2. Playback rates below 0.5 do not work or do not work well. And personally I always recommend using AirPlay over Chromecast from iPhone/iPad devices.

Comment: I can find no way to cast from Chrome on IOS and indeed the Chrome help pages seem to confirm that this is not supported. If you are able to do this, could you share a screen shot?